# Error: Could not resolve 'api.movieDetails' from state 'api'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have been following this tutorial for UI-router in AngularJS:  [UI-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).  I have researched the questions and I couldn't find an answer to my problem that I am having. Its a very simple thing that I am doing, so no advanced techniques here. :)

So, the user should get to the movie details state by clicking on a movie in a list. But whenever I click on it, the console says:

Error: Could not resolve 'api.movieDetails' from state 'api'

How can I fix this?

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('api', {
            url: '/api',
            controller: 'apiController',
            templateUrl: '/movieSearch.html'
        })
        .state('details', {
            url: "/movieDetails/:id",
            templateUrl: "/movieDetails.html"
        });

    //Catch all
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/movie");
});
```

my html snippet:

```
<div>
    <img src="{{movie.posters.thumbnail}}" />
    <a ui-sref="api.details({id: movie.id})"><h2>{{movie.title}}</h2></a>
</div>
```

apiController.js

```
module.exports = function apiController($scope, apiFactory, $stateParams) {
    $scope.data = {}   

    $scope.$watchGroup(['data.q', 'data.page_limit', 'data.page'], function() {
        //Use movie loader
        apiFactory.getMovies($scope.data.q, $scope.data.page_limit, $scope.data.page)
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.movies = response.data.movies
            });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the state `api.details` is missing the "id" parameter, so you need to add it the the state definition:

```
.state('details', {
    url: "/movieDetails/:id",
    templateUrl: "/movieDetails.html"
});
```

And then you need to redirect to the state and pass the parameter of the movie:

```
<a ui-sref="api.details({id: movie.id})"><h2>{{movie.title}}</h2></a>
```

Now, inject `$stateParams` into `apiController` and see the ID that was passed to the state using `console.log($stateParams.id);`

Comment: Did you mean "Now, inject..." instead of "Not, inject..." Subtle, but important difference.

Comment: @Lex Yes :) Thanks

Comment: I have injected the `$stateParams` into the `apiController`, and still no dice. The console still gives me that error. I have updated my post to include the APIcontroller file.

Comment: Does this state (`api.details`) is using `apiController` controller? Or did you  set another controller on the view (Using `ngController`)?

Comment: And make sure that you have also changed `api.movieDetails({movie.id})` to `api.details({id: movie.id})` (I've noticed that it's incorrect in your last edit

Comment: To reply to your first question, `api.details` is indeed using the `apiController` controller.

Comment: Ok, so can you see to ID of the movie that was passed to the controller (Using `console.log($stateParams.id);` - For example)? Do you see the state template (/movieDetails.html)? And are you being redirected to `/api/movieDetails/XXX` (XXX Is the movie id) when you click on the link?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have got it working now! :)